# Centering a upload form

Tags: css

I am wondering how i can center my image upload form.

```
 <div id="uploader" style="width: 450px; height: 330px;">Your browser doesn't support upload.</div>
```

All the other elements like buttons are centered with:

```
.jumbotron {
margin: 60px 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally

Comment: you can use margin:0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's supposed to work this way and it may not work for *all* versions of IE, but for Webkit, FF, etc. it works just fine:

```
div#uploader {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: This works well in [all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin#Browser_compatibility). So, be sure :).

Comment: @Mr_Green a few years ago I tested in IE7 (I think) and if I remember correctly it just sticked to the left of the parent there. But who uses IE7 anyway ... :p